# "count 3" in ReadP parses 3 occurrences. How do I parse between 3 and 8 occurrences?

Tags: haskell

ReadP has this function:

```
count :: Int -> ReadP a -> ReadP [a]

-- Usage:
count 3 $ satisfy (== 'c')
```

I'm wondering if there is a similar function to parse between 3 and 8 occurrences:

```
count_between 3 8 $ satisfy (== 'c')
```

If I have to create my own, how would you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
count_between a b p = (++) <$> count a p <*> count_upto (b - a) p

count_upto 0 _ = pure []
count_upto b p = ((:) <$> p <*> count_upto (b-1) p) +++ pure []
```

Note the similarity to `many`. A `munch`ing variant would use `<++` instead of `+++`.